# \citep in the SIGCHI LaTeX template is not defined

Tags: citing, natbib, undefined

I'm trying to use the SIGCHI LaTeX template from here

https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/tree/master/LaTeX

but if I try to use the `\citep` command It gives the error:

> Undefined control sequence.
>
> l.247 \citep

However, if I manually try to add `natbib` with:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

I get the following error:

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty:639:
>
> LaTeX Error: Command \bibsep already defined.
>
> Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

How could I get `\citep` working?

Comment: As `bibsep` was defined on [line 1436 of sigchi.cls](https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/blob/master/LaTeX/sigchi.cls#L1436), they may not intend for you to use `natbib` at all. I see some exceedingly old-looking code in that class, so tread lightly with any proposed changes.

Comment: The template uses numerical references, both for the Proceedings and Extended Abstract versions, so why do you want to use `\citep` instead of `\cite`?

Comment: With this document class, don't load the `natbib` package. Instead, load the `cite` package -- and use `\cite` instead of ‘\citep` or `\citet`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because neither does the template claim to provide `\citep` nor does it encourage the use of `natbib`.